# Neo4j Web Server Hangs: Logging Issue?

Tags: logging, database, classpath

I have a small database that was working fine just a day ago, but now, when I try to start it, the console claims that it succeeds in opening, but the web server hangs.

```
lsof -i | grep 7474
```

states that neo4j is listening to the port, and "close_wait"-ing, which I'm told means that the server side shut it down.

The only new error I get is that logback.groovy is missing, along with logback-test.xml, which is very odd, because I set logging to false in the neo4j config file. Here's the output when I start neo4j:

```
Starting Neo4j Server...19:31:30,507 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
19:31:30,507 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
19:31:30,508 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.8.1-unix/libexec/system/lib/neo4j-server-1.8.1.jar!/logback.xml]
19:31:30,536 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@33d6f122 - URL [jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/community-1.8.1-unix/libexec/system/lib/neo4j-server-1.8.1.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
19:31:30,632 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
19:31:30,646 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
19:31:30,650 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
19:31:30,670 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
19:31:30,737 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
19:31:30,737 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
19:31:30,740 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.IncludeAction - Could not find resource corresponding to [custom-logback.xml]
19:31:30,742 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@647109c4 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

WARNING: not changing user
process [2350]... waiting for server to be ready...... OK.
Go to http://localhost:7475/webadmin/ for administration interface.
```

I thought that this was a problem with the path, so I appended NEO4J_HOME to the neo4j file, like here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/neo4j/NMVHoflUrHo/warnQUInGCgJ (Bhargava's solution).

Nonetheless, the problem persists. Thoughts? I have no idea what the log files do and why they are needed.

Anyone? Really, even apointer to an explanation might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the open file handle limitations of your system.

Set both maxfiles using launchctl and ulimit -n using ulimit in order to be able to start-up neo4j properly.

Otherwise the symptoms are that this process will just timeout as you've described.